# Why would ReDim throw a Subscript out of range error 9

Tags: excel, dynamic-arrays, excel-2013, vba

My code dynamically creates an array in VB
Public Function getIndvidualCuts(dblsawKerf As Double) As Double() 'returns and array of of all the cuts

```
Dim intQuantity As Integer
intQuantity = 0
Dim i As Integer

intQuantity = 0 ' an integer to store the total quanitiy
For i = 0 To Me.getNumCuts() - 1  'for each different cut
    intQuantity = intQuantity + getCutQuantity(i) 'add the cut quantity to the total quantity
Next

Dim total() As Double 'initialize the total cuts array to make room for each individual cut
ReDim total(intQuantity - 1) **error is here**
```

I don't understand why ReDim throws an Error. I have been searching but all i find are situations where people are using *ReDim Preserve* If you have a different solution for a dynamic array please share it

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible for the subscript to be -1 (i.e., intQuantity = 0). I don't believe you can have that.

Comment: Yep. I agree with @MattCremeens. Most likely Me.getNumbCuts() is returning either 1 or 0, which causes intQuantity to stay at 0, and since you can't have an array of -1 length, you get an error.

Comment: Also, if `getCutQuantity` returns a non-integer, I believe you may run into trouble.

Comment: That's what it was @MattCremeens. Thanks for the help. I found the error and its fixed now thanks for helping my simple error.

Comment: @MattCremeens post your suggestion as answer and Noah user can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples of invalid array subscripts would be non-integer or negative subscripts. If `intQuantity = 0` at any point in your program, then that would produce a subscript for your array of -1. Similarly, if `getCutQuantity` returns a non-integer, then your array subscript would be a non-integer. Glad that helped.